# keynav - Fedora (25) installation

Tags: installation, fedora, make

I have recently had difficulty installing "keynav" (a utility for keyboard control of mouse pointer). The first problem:

```
keynav.c:29:17: fatal error: xdo.h: No such file or directory
#include <xdo.h>
                ^
compilation terminated.
```

And once that was solved the second:

```
cc keynav.o -o keynav -lcairo -lXinerama -lglib-2.0 -lXext -lX11 -lXtst -lglib-2.0 -lxdo; \

keynav.o: In function `parse_mods':
keynav.c:(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `xdo_symbol_map'
keynav.o: In function `cmd_start':
keynav.c:(.text+0x1a1e): undefined reference to `xdo_window_setclass'
keynav.o: In function `cmd_cursorzoom':
keynav.c:(.text+0x20bb): undefined reference to `xdo_mouselocation'
keynav.o: In function `cmd_windowzoom':
keynav.c:(.text+0x212f): undefined reference to `xdo_window_get_active'
keynav.o: In function `cmd_warp':
keynav.c:(.text+0x22d9): undefined reference to `xdo_mousemove'
keynav.c:(.text+0x22f5): undefined reference to `xdo_mouse_wait_for_move_to'
keynav.o: In function `cmd_click':
keynav.c:(.text+0x235f): undefined reference to `xdo_click'
keynav.o: In function `cmd_drag':
keynav.c:(.text+0x2487): undefined reference to `xdo_mouseup'
keynav.c:(.text+0x24c3): undefined reference to `xdo_keysequence_down'
keynav.c:(.text+0x24df): undefined reference to `xdo_mousedown'
keynav.c:(.text+0x24fd): undefined reference to `xdo_mousemove_relative'
keynav.c:(.text+0x251b): undefined reference to `xdo_mousemove_relative'
keynav.c:(.text+0x2555): undefined reference to `xdo_keysequence_up'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:31: recipe for target 'keynav' failed
make: *** [keynav] Error 1
```

However I now have it successfully installed so I will post the answer in case anyone else needs it!

Answer (score 2):

So the first problem is caused by not having the *development* version of the xdo library, and is fixed by

```
dnf install libxdo-devel
```

The second problem is caused by the file `keynav.c` having a bunch of incorrectly named calls from the `xdo.h` header file. (I'm assuming some inconsistency between versions here but haven't looked into it.)

Either way, these can be fixed by hand, by finding the similarly named functions in the header file and editing the names in the source file. Here is the result of `diff` of the amended and the original:

```
292c289
<   const char **symbol_map = xdo_get_symbol_map(); 
---
>   const char **symbol_map = xdo_symbol_map();
846c843
<     xdo_set_window_class(xdo, zone, "keynav", "keynav");
---
>     xdo_window_setclass(xdo, zone, "keynav", "keynav");
1004c1001
<   xdo_get_mouse_location(xdo, &xloc, &yloc, NULL);
---
>   xdo_mouselocation(xdo, &xloc, &yloc, NULL);
1019c1016
<   xdo_get_active_window(xdo, &curwin);
---
>   xdo_window_get_active(xdo, &curwin);
1048,1049c1045,1046
<   xdo_move_mouse(xdo, x, y, viewports[wininfo.curviewport].screen_num);
<   xdo_wait_for_mouse_move_to(xdo, x, y);
---
>   xdo_mousemove(xdo, x, y, viewports[wininfo.curviewport].screen_num);
>   xdo_mouse_wait_for_move_to(xdo, x, y);
1062c1059
<     xdo_click_window(xdo, CURRENTWINDOW, button);
---
>     xdo_click(xdo, CURRENTWINDOW, button);
1100c1097
<     xdo_mouse_up(xdo, CURRENTWINDOW, button);
---
>     xdo_mouseup(xdo, CURRENTWINDOW, button);
1104,1105c1101,1102
<     xdo_send_keysequence_window_down(xdo, 0, drag_modkeys, 12000);
<     xdo_mouse_down(xdo, CURRENTWINDOW, button);
---
>     xdo_keysequence_down(xdo, 0, drag_modkeys, 12000);
>     xdo_mousedown(xdo, CURRENTWINDOW, button);
1109,1110c1106,1107
<     xdo_move_mouse_relative(xdo, 1, 0);
<     xdo_move_mouse_relative(xdo, -1, 0);
---
>     xdo_mousemove_relative(xdo, 1, 0);
>     xdo_mousemove_relative(xdo, -1, 0);
1112c1109
<     xdo_send_keysequence_window_up(xdo, 0, drag_modkeys, 12000);
---
>     xdo_keysequence_up(xdo, 0, drag_modkeys, 12000);
```

As you can see, it is only the names of the functions that need to be changed, not the parameters.

[If you don't know `diff`: in this case the line(s) above each `---` are the new ones (starting with `<`) and the line(s) below each `---` are the old ones that were changed (starting with `>`, and that you will need to change too in your `keynav.c` file.)]

**Hope that helps!**